# Debugging C in Eclipse - "Can't find source file"

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging

I've installed Eclipse for C/C++ Developer and cygwin, following [this guide](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html). Also, in `Preferences > C/C++ > Enviroment`, I added all variables. I mounted /c to c: in cygwin, and now when I type `mount` in the terminal I get the following:

```
$ mount 
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,user)
```

My program builds and runs successfully in Eclipse, but when I try to debug (adding a breakpoint on the first line), I get the **error**:

```
Can't find a source file at "/cygdrive/c/Users/steve/eclipse-workspace/myProgram/myProgram.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

I then found [this guide](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/57027/) to deal with this error, so that my Path Mapping was `/cygdrive/c C:\`

However, I now get the **following error** when trying to debug:

```
Can't find a source file at "/usr/src/debug/gcc-7.4.0-1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

I don't know where to go from here, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you forced to use cygwin? Do you need a POSIX layer? You may find things easier to deal with with a closer-to-native MinWG development environment.

Comment: How do you try to debug? The source mentioned is not yours and therefore not provided. Set a breakpoint at the first line of `main()` and then run the debuggee.

Comment: What do you mean by the source mentioned is not mine?